# Android phone ICS cannot connect to internet through LAN

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi

I have an Android phone that connects to my local area network via WiFi. The LAN consists of a switch and a Debian box that acts as a router, with two interfaces: one external and one internal. For some reason, after updating to Ice Cream Sandwich, my phone can no longer get through to the internet although it can connect to all machines on my LAN.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this routing problem? When I try to access the net from the phone, I see `ARP, Request`s that seem to go unanswered, eg:

> ARP, Request who-has yyz06s05-in-f7.1e100.net tell ...

It seems as if traffic isn't getting routed back to my phone properly. I run my own DNS, one internal and one external.

Thanks for any ideas.

P.S. I downloaded an nslookup utility onto the phone (using cellular network, which does work) and the phone properly gets served DNS from my home network.  Also, FYI, other devices connect to the WiFi fine.  Finally, the phone MAC address *DOES* appear in arp -i eth1 output.  I am thoroughly confused.

Comment: you did not mention any details of your WIFI AP/router configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are getting DHCP to your internal network vLAN only.

But its definitely a routing issue.
Can you set manual route from your phone IP to WAN port?